# unordered_map in namespace is not "saving" its data across source files

Tags: c++

I have a namespace that has an std::unordered_map inside it but the data isn't saving between different including source files. Lets say if I add data to the map in one source file and want to go to another source file to read this data in the map, the map is completely empty. If I check the map in the source file that fills the map, it sees the data perfectly fine.

This is my namespace in question:

```cpp
namespace Command {
    using Verb = std::function<
        void(
            DexunClientClass&,
            SleepyDiscord::Message&,
            std::queue<std::string>&
            )
    >;

    struct Command {
        std::string name;
        std::vector<std::string> params;
        std::string description;
        Verb verb;
    };
    using MappedCommands = std::unordered_map<std::string, Command>;
    using MappedCommand = MappedCommands::value_type;
    static MappedCommands all;
    static void addCommand(Command command) {
        all.emplace(command.name, command);
    }
}
```

The unordered map that gets added to is "MappedCommands all"

And example of how I add to it in another source file:

```cpp
Command::addCommand(command); // command was defined earlier.
```

If I go to another source file and try to access it like:

```cpp
Command::all
```

Then the unordered map is completely empty.

I am expecting that the map would be filled with the data that was added to the map by one source file be the same in another file, but its empty.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Is the blocked named "_my namespace in question:_" is in the header, that is included in multiple files? Do you know what `static` means in `static MappedCommands all;`?

Comment: `static MappedCommands all;` should be `extern MappedCommands all;`,, and you need to define `all` in exactly one source file. As written, there's a different `all` in each source file.

Comment: @PeteBecker I removed the static, and it works now. Used to Java's static which afaik, is different then C++'s. Thanks! Make sure to add it to the answer below.

Comment: @SeanOMik `static` can mean different things in C++ depending on where it's used. If you use it on a class member it will behave like java's `static`.

Comment: @SeanOMik Java has no namespace scope variables at all, so there is no directly comparable functionality.

Comment: @SeanOMik *Used to Java's static which afaik, is different then C++'s* -- Never, ever use another language as a model in writing C++ code.  That's the moral of this story.

Answer (score 1):

What you are observing is to be expected. Each translation unit has their own instance of the static variable. That's what static means (in namespace scope). Note that `static` keyword does not affect the storage duration class in this case. The storage duration is static in either case. `static` keyword affects the linkage of the variable.

If you want all translation units to share the same variable, then you need to make it non static. In this case, be wary of static initialisation order fiasco.